# Incorrect Java application deployment in tomcat6 on linux

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, tomcat, deployment

In Linux environment, when I keep my Java web-application's `war` file into `webapps` directory and start the server, it strangely gets extracted to 2 different applications (with 2nd one unwanted application with first letter removed).

More specifically, I have application war file as `configurator.war`, I'm copying it to `webapps` directory of tomcat and starting server with `./startup.sh` in Linux environment. But this extracts 2 folders `configurator` & `onfigurator` (don't know how).

Can anybody please suggest what wrong I might have done?

Comment: Could you do from Linux console, in an empty temporary directory: `unzip -q configurator.war` and see what you get? Just to make sure the format of the zip (WAR) file is OK.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos after specifying this command `unzip -q configurator.war` it extracted all the files in war out there in the folder where configurator.war is existing. Any suggestions?